# How did Adam and Chava meet?

Tags: sources-mekorot, parashat-bereishit, adam, eve-chava

> וַיְבִאֶהָ אֶל־הָאָדָם׃
>
> and [Hashem] brought her [Chava] to the man [Adam] ([Bereshit 2:22](https://www.sefaria.org/Chizkuni%2C_Genesis.2.22?lang=bi))

Hashem brought Chava to Adam. I saw in the commentaries that there seems to be a reason to think that "brought" is an idiom. Adam awoke and saw her, and thought she had been brought to him like the animals, to be named. Another idea floats around that she was indeed made outside the Gan, and brought to him literally, or at least that that's what he thought.

I would like to know more about this first meeting between Chava and Adam. **Any more details about the event**, for one. **Lessons we learn from it**, for another, e.g. it seems like she might have first seen him asleep. What teachings do we derive from this? Why (in the first and last opinions I mentioned) does the Torah describe the event from Adam's perceptual point of view rather than a standard third person narration?

Comment: Mods, I strongly suspect you will advise me to break this up into 2 or 3 questions?

Comment: Eitz Yosef on Shabbat 95b states: 
ויבאה אל האדם שהביאה ממקום אחר כי לא רצה לתקנה בפניו לבל תתגנה בעיניו. And He brought her to Man. He brought her from another place because He did not want to form her in front of him lest she become repugnant in his eyes.